# How to show Google places reviews on site using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-places-api

I'm trying to show all the google reviews of a company I work for on the site but I can't really seem to get it to work.
I've tried to use the following code for this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var people = [];
        $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=<?php echo $placeId ?>&key=<?php echo $api_key ?>', function(data) {
            $.each(data.reviews, function(i, f) {
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.author_name + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + f.rating + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.relative_time_description + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.text + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#google-reviews");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In here I'm supposed to get a response that looks similar to this json file:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      ...
      "rating" : 4.5,
      "reference" : "CmRSAAAAjiEr2_A4yI-DyqGcfsceTv-IBJXHB5-W3ckmGk9QAYk4USgeV8ihBcGBEK5Z1w4ajRZNVAfSbROiKbbuniq0c9rIq_xqkrf_3HpZzX-pFJuJY3cBtG68LSAHzWXB8UzwEhAx04rgN0_WieYLfVp4K0duGhTU58LFaqwcaex73Kcyy0ghYOQTkg",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
            "time" : 1491144016
         }
      ],
      "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10281119596374313554",
      "utc_offset" : 600,
      "vicinity" : "5, 48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
      "website" : "https://www.google.com.au/about/careers/locations/sydney/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

and every time I get the following 2 errors:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid={placeid}&key={apikey} net::ERR_FAILED
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid={placeid}&key={apikey}' from origin '{the site I work on}' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

is there anyone that know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it in a different way, I made a file called googleData.php which I'll execute twice a day using cron job, with the following code:

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
$api_key = $config["apikey"];
$placeId = $config["locationId"];
$response = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=$placeId&fields=name,rating,reviews&key=$api_key");
//$json = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $response);

$fp = fopen('googleData.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $response);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

this gave the following response in the file googleData.json:

```
  {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "name" : "name",
      "rating" : 4.7,
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "NAME",
            "author_url" : "URL",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "PHOTO_URL",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "5 months ago",
            "text" : "Very helpful.",
            "time" : 1570537557
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "NAME",
            "author_url" : "URL",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "PHOTO_URL",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "5 months ago",
            "text" : "Very helpful.",
            "time" : 1570537557
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "NAME",
            "author_url" : "URL",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "PHOTO_URL",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "5 months ago",
            "text" : "Very helpful.",
            "time" : 1570537557
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "NAME",
            "author_url" : "URL",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "PHOTO_URL",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "5 months ago",
            "text" : "Very helpful.",
            "time" : 1570537557
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "NAME",
            "author_url" : "URL",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "PHOTO_URL",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "5 months ago",
            "text" : "Very helpful.",
            "time" : 1570537557
         }
      ]
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

which I could then use in another file called getreviews.php which had the following code:

```
var json = $.getJSON("googleData.json", function(response) {
    var result = response.result;
})
```

with which I was was able to show every value of the json I got from google.

for the ones who are curious, this is what I had in the config.php:

```
<?php
    $config["apikey"] = "API_KEY";
    $config["locationId"] = "PLACE_ID";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know in order to use Places Details via client-side application you should use Places Library in Maps JavaScript API.
Here is docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

So first you need to include Google Maps api with Places library enabled and map container:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="google-reviews"></div>
</body>
```

And then execute the request:

```
<script>
var request = {
  placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4',
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);

function callback(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(place);
        $.each(place.reviews, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.author_name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + f.rating + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.relative_time_description + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.text + "</td>" + "</tr>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#google-reviews");
    });

  }
}
</script>
```

Here is example:
https://jsfiddle.net/scarabs/we541sqg/1/

Comment: When I try this I get this error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined

Comment: Have you included ```<div id="map"></div>``` in your html? I get this error when there is no map container on page.